# Incorrect Syntax Near the Keyword "ON" Error Message - Editing existing SQL Query

Tags: t-sql

I am trying to edit an existing SQL RDL Query to change a report slightly that was provided by a supplier of software. In trying to change the report, I thought I had removed all references to the previous equation but I am now presented with the following error message

> Query execution failed for dataset 'MainDataSource' (rsErrorExecutingCommand)
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword "ON"

Is there a way to go about finding exactly where the error exists in the code, searching for the keyword "ON" doesn't seem to be successful.

The code is quite large which is why I haven't posted here but I can if that's the only way to answer?

Cheers

````
DECLARE @EmptyGuid uniqueidentifier = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Cycles') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Cycles
CREATE TABLE #Cycles 
(
    Id uniqueidentifier
    ,CycleStart datetime
    ,CycleEnd datetime
    ,TruckId uniqueidentifier
    ,LoadWeight int
    ,LoadDuration int
    ,LoadStart datetime
    ,LoaderId uniqueidentifier
    ,PRIMARY KEY (Id)
    ,UNIQUE (CycleStart, Id)
    ,UNIQUE (CycleEnd, Id)
    ,UNIQUE (LoadStart, Id)
    ,UNIQUE (LoaderId, Id)
)
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#History') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #History
CREATE TABLE #History
(
    Id uniqueidentifier
    ,MachineId uniqueidentifier
    ,ActivityId uniqueidentifier
    ,StartDatetime datetime
    ,EndDatetime datetime
    ,PRIMARY KEY (Id)
    ,UNIQUE (MachineId, Id)
    ,UNIQUE (ActivityId, Id)
    ,UNIQUE (StartDatetime, Id)
    ,UNIQUE (EndDatetime, Id)
)
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#CycleIds') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #CycleIds
CREATE TABLE #CycleIds 
(
    Id uniqueidentifier
    ,PRIMARY KEY(Id)
)
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#NumberedCycleLoaders') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #NumberedCycleLoaders
CREATE TABLE #NumberedCycleLoaders
(
    Id uniqueidentifier
    ,LoaderId uniqueidentifier
    ,RowNumber int
    ,UNIQUE (LoaderId, Id)
    ,UNIQUE (RowNumber, Id)
)

-- Get the site defined activities for shutdown and idle for all loading unit types.
DECLARE @LoaderDownActivities TABLE (Id uniqueidentifier, PRIMARY KEY (Id))
INSERT INTO @LoaderDownActivities
SELECT  DISTINCT a.Id
FROM    Activity a
        INNER JOIN OnboardActivityDefault oad ON a.Id = oad.ActivityId
        INNER JOIN OnboardActivity oa ON oad.OnboardActivityId = oa.Id
WHERE   -- onboard activity for Shutdown and Idel
        oa.Id IN ('D8FE016D-9457-466A-8866-15678FFC3F35', 'CC704887-0667-4950-9491-75CF761E7A2A')
        -- machine types for loader and excavator
        AND oad.MachineTypeId IN ('E32A4E32-E453-462B-AED6-D2A87EE29AF7', '04733AA5-51A0-41E8-8B23-13FE9C85221D')

/* ******************************************************** */

-- First get the Ids from the cycle table to limit the strain on the join to Running History
INSERT INTO #CycleIds
SELECT  Id
FROM    TruckCycle
WHERE   CycleStart &gt;= @ReportStartUTC
        AND CycleStart &lt; @ReportEndUTC

UNION ALL
-- Also get the last cycle before the reporting period.
SELECT  Id
FROM    (
            SELECT  Id
                    ,RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TruckId ORDER BY CycleStart DESC)
            FROM    TruckCycle 
            WHERE   CycleStart &lt; @ReportStartUTC
        ) sq
WHERE   RowNumber = 1

-- Get the Truck Loading History - this is so we can determine the time at which each loading period occurred
-- Which will give us the operator of the loading unit
;WITH truckLoadingActivities AS (
    SELECT  DISTINCT a.Id
    FROM    Activity a
            INNER JOIN OnboardActivityDefault oad ON a.Id = oad.ActivityId
            INNER JOIN OnboardActivity oa ON oad.OnboardActivityId = oa.Id
    WHERE   -- onboard activity for Loading
            oa.Id = '9ADBE536-C112-4E6E-9EA4-AE4973FA9C98'
            -- machine types for Truck and Road Train
            AND oad.MachineTypeId IN ('16D31A04-0377-4AC5-AE40-917E1516E54E', 'B9688837-261F-42F7-8545-C451245D842F')
)
INSERT INTO #History (Id, MachineId, StartDatetime, EndDatetime)
SELECT  h.Id
        ,h.MachineId
        ,h.StartDatetime
        ,h.EndDatetime
FROM    RunningHistory h 
        INNER JOIN truckLoadingActivities a ON h.ActivityId = a.Id
WHERE   -- Also limit the history on loading activities that occurred during the period.
        h.StartDatetime &gt;= @ReportStartUTC
        AND h.StartDatetime &lt; @ReportEndUTC

-- Now extract the cycle information, along with the first loading timestamp of the truck involved in each cycle.
INSERT INTO #Cycles (Id, CycleStart, CycleEnd, TruckId, LoadWeight, LoadDuration, LoadStart)
SELECT  c.Id
        ,c.CycleStart
        ,c.CycleEnd
        ,c.TruckId
        ,c.LoadWeight
        ,c.LoadDuration
        ,MIN(h.StartDatetime) as LoadStart
FROM    TruckCycle c
        INNER JOIN #CycleIds cids ON c.Id = cids.Id
        INNER JOIN #History h 
            ON c.TruckId = h.MachineId 
            AND (h.StartDatetime BETWEEN c.CycleStart AND c.CycleEnd)
GROUP BY
        c.Id
        ,c.CycleStart
        ,c.CycleEnd
        ,c.TruckId
        ,c.LoadWeight
        ,c.LoadDuration

-- To determine the loader for each cycle, we have to select one of many.
-- Do a simple selection by numbering each loader associated with each cycle, and then pick the first one (ordered by loader description)
INSERT INTO #NumberedCycleLoaders (Id, LoaderId, RowNumber)
SELECT  CycleId
        ,cl.LoaderId
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CycleId ORDER BY l.Description ASC) AS LoaderNumber
FROM    TruckCycleLoader cl
        INNER JOIN #CycleIds c ON cl.CycleId = c.Id
        INNER JOIN Machine l ON l.Id = cl.LoaderId

-- Now update the cycle information with the loaders
UPDATE  c
SET     c.LoaderId = cl.LoaderId
FROM    #Cycles c
        INNER JOIN #NumberedCycleLoaders cl ON c.Id = cl.Id
            ON cl.LoaderId = op.MachineId 
            AND (c.LoadStart BETWEEN op.StartDatetime AND op.EndDatetime)
WHERE   cl.RowNumber = 1

-- Remove cycles that have been filtered out by the user - to limit the next lot of queries.
DELETE FROM #Cycles
WHERE   (@MachineId IS NOT NULL AND LoaderId &lt;&gt; @MachineId)
        AND (@MachineTypeId IS NOT NULL AND LoaderId NOT IN (SELECT Id FROM Machine WHERE MachineTypeId = @MachineTypeId))
        AND (@MachineGroupId IS NOT NULL AND (LoaderId NOT IN (SELECT MachineId FROM MachineGroupMachine WHERE MachineGroupId = @MachineGroupId)))

-- Clear history table
DELETE FROM #History

-- Get the Running History records for each loader over the reporting period.
INSERT INTO #History (Id, MachineId, ActivityId, StartDatetime, EndDatetime)
SELECT  h.Id
        ,h.MachineId
        ,h.ActivityId
        ,h.StartDatetime 
        ,ISNULL(CASE WHEN h.EndDatetime &gt; @ReportEndUTC THEN @ReportEndUTC ELSE h.EndDatetime END, @ReportEndUTC) as EndDatetime
FROM    RunningHistory h
WHERE   h.MachineId IN (SELECT LoaderId FROM #Cycles)
        AND h.StartDatetime &gt;= @ReportStartUTC
        AND h.StartDatetime &lt; @ReportEndUTC

-- The previous query retrieved all activities up to the end of the period, however 
-- it will most likely have missed the first activity history (unless it started exactly on the reporting period start).
-- Include the last activity before the reporting period for each loader.
INSERT INTO #History (Id, MachineId, ActivityId, StartDatetime, EndDatetime)
SELECT  h.Id
        ,h.MachineId
        ,h.ActivityId
        ,CASE WHEN h.StartDatetime &lt; @ReportStartUTC THEN @ReportStartUTC ELSE h.StartDatetime  END as StartDatetime
        ,ISNULL(CASE WHEN h.EndDatetime &gt; @ReportEndUTC THEN @ReportEndUTC ELSE h.EndDatetime END, @ReportEndUTC) as EndDatetime
FROM    (
            SELECT  Id
                    ,StartDatetime 
                    ,ISNULL(EndDatetime, @ReportEndUTC) as EndDatetime
                    ,MachineId
                    ,ActivityId
                    ,OnboardActivityId
                    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MachineId ORDER BY StartDatetime DESC) AS LoaderHistoryNumber
            FROM    RunningHistory
            WHERE   MachineId IN (SELECT LoaderId FROM #Cycles)
                    -- Use Less than so we don't include anything retrieved from the above query
                    AND StartDatetime &lt; @ReportStartUTC
        ) as h
WHERE   LoaderHistoryNumber = 1

-- Get the total time recorded for each loading unit combination
-- The loading units are filtered by the cycles selected (see query above)
DECLARE @LoaderTimes TABLE 
(
    Id uniqueidentifier
    ,DelayDuration int NULL
    ,ProductionDuration int NULL 
    ,TotalDuration int NULL 
)
INSERT INTO @LoaderTimes (Id, TotalDuration)
SELECT  h.MachineId
        ,SUM(DATEDIFF(second, h.StartDatetime, ISNULL(h.EndDatetime, @ReportEndUTC))) as LoaderTotalTime
FROM    #History h
GROUP BY 
        h.MachineId

-- Now Get the time each loader and operator spends in Delay/Down activities over the reporting period.
UPDATE  lt
SET     lt.DelayDuration = ISNULL(Duration, 0)
FROM    @LoaderTimes lt
        INNER JOIN 
        (
            SELECT  _lt.Id
                    ,SUM(DATEDIFF(second, _h.StartDatetime, ISNULL(_h.EndDatetime, @ReportEndUTC))) as Duration
            FROM    @LoaderTimes _lt
                    INNER JOIN #History _h ON _h.MachineId = _lt.Id
                    INNER JOIN Activity _a ON _h.ActivityId = _a.Id
                    LEFT JOIN @LoaderDownActivities _lda ON _h.ActivityId = _lda.Id
            WHERE   (
                        -- Delay activity type
                        _a.ActivityTypeId = '9BA50462-B007-4383-AA86-4427958867E2'
                        -- or a loader down activity (shutdown / idle)
                        OR _lda.Id IS NOT NULL
                    )
            GROUP BY
                    _lt.Id
        ) lt2 ON lt.Id = lt2.Id

-- Now update the production time in the temporary LoaderTimes table to be Total - Delay.
UPDATE  @LoaderTimes
SET     ProductionDuration = TotalDuration - ISNULL(DelayDuration, 0)

-- Get the final results.
SELECT  LoaderId
        ,l.Description as LoaderDescription
        ,lt.TotalDuration
        ,DelayDuration
        ,ProductionDuration
        ,count(*) as LoadCount
        ,SUM(LoadWeight) as TotalWeight
        ,SUM(LoadDuration) as TotalLoadDuration
        ,SUM(CONVERT(decimal(19,4), LoadWeight)) / SUM(CONVERT(decimal(19,4), CASE LoadDuration WHEN 0 THEN NULL ELSE LoadDuration END)) * 3600.0 as InstantaneousDigRate
        ,CASE ProductionDuration WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE SUM(CONVERT(decimal(19,4), LoadWeight)) / ProductionDuration * 3600.0 END as AverageProductivityDigRate

FROM    #Cycles c
        INNER JOIN Machine l ON c.LoaderId = l.Id
        -- We can join on loader times even though we are performing a grouping, this is because
        -- the loader times table has a unique entry for each loader combination.
        LEFT JOIN @LoaderTimes lt ON lt.Id = c.LoaderId
WHERE   (@MachineId IS NULL OR c.LoaderId = @MachineId)
        AND (@MachineTypeId IS NULL OR l.MachineTypeId = @MachineTypeId)
        AND (@MachineGroupId IS NULL OR (c.LoaderId IN (SELECT MachineId FROM MachineGroupMachine WHERE MachineGroupId = @MachineGroupId)))
GROUP BY
        LoaderId
        ,l.Description
        ,lt.TotalDuration
        ,lt.DelayDuration
        ,lt.ProductionDuration
ORDER BY
        l.Description

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Cycles') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Cycles
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#History') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #History
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#CycleIds') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #CycleIds
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#NumberedCycleLoaders') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #NumberedCycleLoaders```
````

Comment: Add the query to your question. We can't guess blindly.

Comment: Sorry I have updated it now.

Comment: Sorry Impaler, I uploaded the wrong edit, that was the working one with Operator reference. please review the current edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query looks wrong. It should not have two `ON` clauses:

```
UPDATE  c
SET     c.LoaderId = cl.LoaderId
FROM    #Cycles c
        INNER JOIN #NumberedCycleLoaders cl ON c.Id = cl.Id
            ON cl.LoaderId = op.MachineId 
            AND (c.LoadStart BETWEEN op.StartDatetime AND op.EndDatetime)
WHERE   cl.RowNumber = 1
```

You probably want:

```
UPDATE  c
SET     c.LoaderId = cl.LoaderId
FROM    #Cycles c
        INNER JOIN #NumberedCycleLoaders cl ON c.Id = cl.Id
            AND cl.LoaderId = op.MachineId -- maybe AND or OR in this line
            AND (c.LoadStart BETWEEN op.StartDatetime AND op.EndDatetime)
WHERE   cl.RowNumber = 1
```

Comment: Hi Impaler, making this change resulted in the following error to now be presented: "The multi-part identifier "op.MachineId" could not be bound. The multi-part identifier "op.StartDatetime" could not be bound. The multi-part identifier "op.EndDatetime" could not be bound"

Comment: You are using the alias `op`, but it's not defined anywhere in that query. Which tables do the columns `MachineId`, `StartDatetime`, and `EndDatetime` belong to?

Comment: Focusing on the area that seems to be causing the issue. I have replaced the code as suggested by Impaler but was still receiving the error below detailed in my comment. 

This is the code I was trying to replace:

```-- Now update the cycle information with the loaders and operators
UPDATE c
SET  c.LoaderId = cl.LoaderId
  ,c.OperatorId = op.OperatorId
FROM #Cycles c
  INNER JOIN #NumberedCycleLoaders cl ON c.Id = cl.Id
  LEFT JOIN #OperatorPeriods op 
   ON cl.LoaderId = op.MachineId 
   AND (c.LoadStart BETWEEN op.StartDatetime AND op.EndDatetime)
WHERE cl.RowNumber = 1```

Comment: Actually removing the reference to the op.machineID, start time etc seems to have resolved the issue. As it was referring to a table/process that wasn't required. The only thing left to change is the answer to report in 1 decimal place! Thanks heaps Impaler